# how to dynamically calculate row values in data.table, avoiding FOR loop

Tags: r, data.table

Think of following cases:

- ad stock in current period t depends on ad stock of t-1, adjusted by some sort of decay, and additional ad contacts in current period
- purchase decision in current period t depends on consumption level by period AND stock level in t-1

It's quite easy to program this as FOR loop. But this becomes very slow when running big data sets (e.g. think 100.000 consumers with daily purchase records for 2 years, that is with more 1 MM row entries).

How can this be programmed with e.g. Data.Table? I know how to use shift function in data.table for given data set. But dynamic calculation in this use case poses some challenge.

I programmed this with FOR loop with data.frame. But performance with huge number of rows is very, very slow

Concept behind the example:
x = think off as e.g ad contact or purchase volume by period etc.

y = think off as dynamic variable such as ad stock which depends on x and decay of y

decay = from any type of function, which calculates y based on previous y values and time generally time period, dynamically changing depending on x - vales | events; here simplified as random function

```
n <- 100
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1,rep(0,n-1)), y = c(1, rep(0,n-1)), decay = c(1, rep(0,n-1)), index=rep(0,n))

set.seed(10)
for(i in 2:n){
  DF$x[i] <- sample(x=c(0:2), replace = T, size = 1, prob = c(0.8, 0.15, 0.05))
  if(DF$x[i] > 0){ DF$index[i] <- 0} else { DF$index[i] <- (DF$index[i-1] + 1) }
  DF$decay[i] <- round((DF$index[i] + 1)^-0.1, 2)
  DF$y[i] <- round((DF$x[i] + DF$y[i-1]) * DF$decay[i],2)}

plot(DF$y, type="o")
```

Comment: What you are basically doing is to create a autoregressive time-series with a certain random impact, correct? I think, just look into the creation of a simple autoregressive time-series, like an AR(1) process.

Comment: The situations I would use / need this type of algorithm are not really auto-regressive time series, but for simulations with (a) time series with covariates (=multiple independent variables) or time series modelling problems for which ARIMA processes do not work (e.g. harzard forecasting).  Running simulations require often that values of independent variables depend on previous periods. The program above is just super simplified with the aim to give a code example.

Comment: Or in situations like Markov processes, where each state of the process depends on the state immediately preceding, so that states need to be generated sequentially. Here I just can think off FOR loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors are your friend. Your current loop extracts a vector from the `data.frame` each pass and that becomes expensive. Instead you should:

1. Create your `x` as a vector all at once
2. Use vectors for the other variables `y, index, and decay`.
3. Declare it as a function - the compiler will improve performance

```
base_loop <- function(x) {
  y <- vector('numeric', n); y[1] <- 1
  decay <- vector('numeric', n); decay[1] <- 1
  index <- vector('integer', n)
  for(i in 2:n){
    if(x[i] > 0){index[i] <- 0} else {index[i] <- (index[i-1] + 1) }
    decay[i] <- (index[i] + 1)^-0.1
    y[i] <- (x[i] + y[i-1]) * decay[i]
  }
  data.frame(x, y, decay, index)
}

set.seed(10)
n = 1E2
x <- c(1,sample(c(0:2), replace = T, size = n-1, prob = c(0.8, 0.15, 0.05)))

DF <- base_loop(x)
```

This can easily be translated into an [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) loop as well:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame decay_func(NumericVector x) {
  IntegerVector ind = x.size();
  NumericVector decay = x.size(); decay[1] = 1;
  NumericVector y = x.size(); y[1] = 1;



  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
    if (x[i] > 0) {
      ind[i] = 0;
    } else {
      ind[i] = ind[i-1] + 1;
    }
    decay[i] = pow(ind[i] + 1,-0.1);
    y[i] = (x[i] + y[i-1]) * decay[i];
  }

  return DataFrame::create(Named("x") = x,
                           Named("y") = y,
                           Named("decay") = decay,
                           Named("index") = ind);
}
```

**Performance**

```
# n = 100 
# A tibble: 4 x 13
  expression          min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>      <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 OP_loop          21.5ms  21.7ms      43.9  702.62KB
2 vector_loop      11.4ms  11.8ms      82.4  100.33KB
3 compiled_vector 473.2us 483.2us    2028.     9.61KB
4 rcpp_func       412.6us 423.3us    2321.    11.27KB

# n = 10,000
# A tibble: 4 x 13
  expression          min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>      <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 OP_loop           1.23s   1.23s     0.816    3.01GB
2 vector_loop     16.73ms 17.11ms    56.2    525.72KB
3 compiled_vector   5.8ms  5.88ms   167.        435KB
4 rcpp_func        1.52ms  1.55ms   606.     359.32KB

# n= 1,000,000
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression        min median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>      <bch> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 vector_loop     563ms  563ms      1.78    42.1MB
2 compiled_vector 556ms  556ms      1.80      42MB
3 rcpp_func       115ms  120ms      7.56    34.3MB
```

Code for reference:

```
library(Rcpp)

set.seed(10)
n = 1E6
x <- c(1,sample(c(0:2), replace = T, size = n-1, prob = c(0.8, 0.15, 0.05)))

bench::mark(
  # OP_loop = {
  #   DF <- data.frame(x = c(1,rep(0,n-1)), y = c(1, rep(0,n-1)), decay = c(1, rep(0,n-1)), index=rep(0,n))
  #   
  #   set.seed(10)
  #   for(i in 2:n){
  #     DF$x[i] <- sample(x=c(0:2), replace = T, size = 1, prob = c(0.8, 0.15, 0.05))
  #     if(DF$x[i] > 0){ DF$index[i] <- 0} else { DF$index[i] <- (DF$index[i-1] + 1) }
  #     DF$decay[i] <- (DF$index[i] + 1)^-0.1
  #     DF$y[i] <- (DF$x[i] + DF$y[i-1]) * DF$decay[i]
  #   }
  #   
  #   DF
  # }
  # ,
  vector_loop = {
    set.seed(10)
    x <- c(1,sample(c(0:2), replace = T, size = n-1, prob = c(0.8, 0.15, 0.05)))

    y <- vector('numeric', n); y[1] <- 1
    decay <- vector('numeric', n); decay[1] <- 1
    index <- vector('integer', n)
    for(i in 2:n){
      if(x[i] > 0){index[i] <- 0} else {index[i] <- (index[i-1] + 1) }
      decay[i] <- (index[i] + 1)^-0.1
      y[i] <- (x[i] + y[i-1]) * decay[i]
    }
    data.frame(x, y, decay, index)
  }
  ,
  compiled_vector = {
    set.seed(10)
    x <- c(1,sample(c(0:2), replace = T, size = n-1, prob = c(0.8, 0.15, 0.05)))

    base_loop(x)
  }
  ,
  rcpp_func = {
    set.seed(10)
    x <- c(1,sample(c(0:2), replace = T, size = n-1, prob = c(0.8, 0.15, 0.05)))

    decay_func(x)
  }
)

decay_base <- function(x) {


    rle_x <- rle(x > 0)

    index <- sequence(rle_x$lengths)
    index[x != 0] <- 0

    decay <- (index + 1)^(-0.1)

    # initialize y vector and other information
    cum_rle_len <- cumsum(rle_x$lengths)
    y <- vector('numeric', n)
    y[1] <- 1

    # loops through the elements of rle
    for (i in seq_len(length(rle_x$values))[-1]){
      prev_ind <- cum_rle_len[i-1]
      ind_rng <- (prev_ind + 1):(prev_ind + rle_x$lengths[i])

      if (rle_x$values[i]) {
        y[ind_rng] <- y[prev_ind] + cumsum(x[ind_rng])
      } else {
        y[ind_rng] <- cumprod(c(y[prev_ind], decay[ind_rng]))[-1]
      }
    }
    data.frame(x, y, decay, index)

}

base_loop <- function(x) {
  y <- vector('numeric', n); y[1] <- 1
  decay <- vector('numeric', n); decay[1] <- 1
  index <- vector('integer', n)
  for(i in 2:n){
    if(x[i] > 0){index[i] <- 0} else {index[i] <- (index[i-1] + 1) }
    decay[i] <- (index[i] + 1)^-0.1
    y[i] <- (x[i] + y[i-1]) * decay[i]
  }
  data.frame(x, y, decay, index)
}
```